# Attribute ranking in weka ends up 0 for all attributes

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka

I am classifying 755 classes with 1024 attributes in weka. I suppose I need to select best attributes for better accuracy. I tried to select attributes using InfoGainAttributeEval and Ranker method but all the attributes ranked as '0'. I am not sure what is wrong. Any help is appreciated.

[image: weka]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you add code snippets that show others where to start?

Comment: @MWiesner I am using weka gui so I do not have any code snippets. Screenshot is added, you can see the problem in the output.

Comment: Without having your data it is hardly possible to help.  On the first sight it looks ok.

Comment: Nice answer below and you might want to ask future questions like this on [the Stack Exchange site for stats, Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tour), granted someone here answered you nicely but there's probably a higher concentration of ML people there http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2):

The "0" here is not the ranking of each attribute, but the **InfoGain** of each attribute.

When you apply InfoGainAttributeEval on Weka, the 3 columns corresponds to : 
Information Gain | "id" of the attribute | name of the attribute.

What happened here might be that the information gain was too small and  has been rounded.

But again, as stated by @CAFEBABE in the comments, without having your data it is hardly possible to be sure.

Edit : A post [here](http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/Somewhat-strange-behavior-of-InfoGainAttributeEval-td14437.html) indicates that the precision of the output is set to four decimal places, which seems to confirm the above hypothesis.